The import scip cannot be resolved Java(268435846)
I've followed the steps on the documentation for macOS but looks like my Java environment is unable to detect scip.
Did the manual installation with optimization suit as well. Is it supposed to generate scip.jar or jscip.jar?

I suggest opening an issue on JSCIPOpt's Github Page. I think they will be more helpful. I assume you have set the correct PATH variables. It seems that the INSTALL.md is 4 years old, so it might be outdated.
